# Do any projects exist for PHP that is similar to ActiveMerchant for Ruby?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I'm curious if anyone is aware of something for PHP with similar, universal payment processor functionality that exists with ActiveMerchant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking something like Active Merchant in PHP check [this](http://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant) at github

Comment: I used AktiveMerchant for a past project, and while it didn't totally solve my headache with PayFlow Pro (PayPal's APIs are horrible, especially PayFlow) it made things much easier -- as in, I was actually able to integrate, which was just not possible with PayPal's reference implementation, various libraries, or the roll-my-own route.

Comment: This Aktive Merchant [fork](https://github.com/tomglue/Aktive-Merchant) has some good improvements for PayFlow. Also i agree about Paypal apis. You have to study hard to understand how things work.

Answer (score 2):

I also know this is an oldie but you should definitely check out omnipay: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay

It is by far the most thought out solution for universal payment gateways with php. Supports a ton of processors, it's unit tested, build from the grounds up for php 5.3+ and it's quite active

Answer (score 1):

Nice! I may port it to PHP in the future.

Meanwhile the closest thing I know of are some [PEAR Payment packages](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=18&catname=Payment) and [Kohana Payment Module](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/payment).

Comment: Thanks.  The Kohana Payment Module looks like it can offer some help.  I've written a somewhat extensive PHP PayPal class (http://github.com/drewjoh/phpPayPal) to access many of the PayPal API functions offered, so perhaps combining the Kohana module with that will offer functionality for other gateways and provide a good base to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just wanted to share another option. [Tala Payments](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/tala-payments) is a composer supported payment library.